# if-statement won't run in for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm working through the FreeCodeCamp basic algorithm scripting section, and I'm a bit stuck on this one.

Basically - I need to find the longest word in a sentence.

1. I've set two variables, `stringArray` and `longestString`
2. I set each word in the argument to an item in an array
3. I iterate through that array, writing a word length to the variable `longestString` if it is longer than the last.
4. I return the variable `longestString`

Why is this not working?

When evaluating `longestString.length`, I keep getting the error:

> undefined is not an object

It seems like maybe the *if* statement is not running in my *for* loop. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

```js
let stringArray = [];
let longestString;
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  stringArray = str.split(' ')
  console.log(stringArray);
  for (let i = 0; i <= stringArray.length; i++){
    if (stringArray[i].length > longestString.length){
      longestString = stringArray[i].length
    }
  }
  return longestString
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

The code above produces the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: You didn't set it anywhere

Comment: I am sure the error message in your console is telling you something.

Comment: in your first iteration  `longestString` is undefined, so `longestString.length` doesn't exists... that's why  you see that error. Open the devTools with F12 and debug your code

Comment: console.log('longestString', longestString) . --> will show you it is undefined. Now undefined does not have a length

Comment: On line 7, try: `if (longestString === undefined || stringArray[i].length > longestString.length){`

Comment: or just start with `let longestString = "";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to fix your code, you'll need to give `longestString` an initial value, use `<` instead of `<=` in the loop and assign the actual string not its length ( inside the if )

```js
let stringArray = [];
let longestString;
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  stringArray = str.split(" ");
  longestString = stringArray[0]; // give longestString an initial value
  for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) { // use < instead of <=
    if (stringArray[i].length > longestString.length) {
      longestString = stringArray[i]; // assign the string not the length
    }
  }

  return longestString;
}

var result = findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result);
```

You can shorten your function by using this trick : split the string into an array of words and sort it by the length of the words and pick the first one :

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  const longest = str.split(" ").sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
  return longest;
}

const result = findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can simply achieve with `Math.max()`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate you taking the time to explain the errors and also provide cleaner code. I'm new to this and still learning!

Answer (score 1):

`let longestString;` <-- sets it to undefined

In your first loop you read it and check its length. Well undefined values do not have a length.

What to do?

Either set it to an empty string or check to make sure the string is set before reading the length.

so you can do

```
let longestString = "";
```

or

```
if (!longestString || stringArray[i].length > longestString.length){
```

or what most people will do set it to the first index

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  // Don't define these outside or they will be reused!
  const stringArray = str.split(' ')
  // set to first index
  let longestString = stringArray[0]
  // start loop at 2nd index
  for (let i = 1; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    if (stringArray[i].length > longestString.length){
      longestString = stringArray[i].length
    }
  }
  return longestString
}

const result = findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result)
```

Other issue is you checked one too many indexes in your loop with a `<=`

Answer (score 0):

Need to initialize `longestString` variable

You can also do it like this

```js
let stringArray = [];
let longestString;
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  stringArray = str.trim().split(' ')
  stringArray = stringArray.sort((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? -1 : (a.length == b.length ? 0 : 1));
  console.log(stringArray)
  return stringArray[0].length
}

let result = findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
console.log(result)
```

Your solution after fix:

```js
let stringArray = [];
let longestString;
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  stringArray = str.split(' ')
  console.log(stringArray);
  longestString = stringArray[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < longestString.length; i++){
    if (stringArray[i].length > longestString.length){
      longestString = stringArray[i].length
    }
  }
  return longestString
}

let result = findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you had `<=` so the loop would run 1 extra time where the item in the array at that index is undefined.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let stringArray = str.split(' ')
  let longestString = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
    if (stringArray[i].length > longestString.length){
      longestString = stringArray[i]
    }
  }
  return longestString
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 0):

You got that error of `.length of undefined` because the last value of your index was `undefined`, because you check the index with less than or equal `<=`.

If your array have 5 elements then you can get value with index up to `array[4]`.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array[4]); // 5
```

If you try to access value with array length which is 5 then you got `undefined`

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array[5]); // undefined
```

```js
    let stringArray = [];
let lgStr = null;

function maxLength(str) {
        const array = str.split(' ');
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
                const elem = array[i];
                if (i === 0) {
                        lgStr = elem;
                }
                if (elem.length > lgStr.length) {
                        lgStr = elem;
                }
        }

        console.log(lgStr);
        return lgStr;
}

maxLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

You can make it very simple with `.sort()`;

```js
   
  function maxLength(str) {
        const lgStr = str.split(' ').sort((a, b) => {
                return b.length - a.length;
        })[0];
        console.log(lgStr);
        return lgStr;
}

maxLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: `Math.max` will give you the length of the longest word, not the longest word itself

Comment: @Taki Oops i thought OP wants it's index

Comment: @Taki Thanks  for the update, Let me correct my answer then

Comment: @Taki Updated the answer